# Install Cinnamon on Debian

Tags: debian, linux-mint, gnome-shell, cinnamon

Is it possible to install Cinnamon on Debian unstable?

There is no packages for Debian on their official [download page](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?page_id=61), and when i tried to add [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable) to my repositories list, it won't install because of lacking dependencies.

#### Edit (01.05.12)

My actions. I downloaded the [source](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/tags), then ran `./configure` in the folder. I got that:

`configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.40 or later.`

There were 2 packages, `intltool` (version 0.50.2) and `intltool-debian` (version 0.35.0), so i installed the first one. Then it complained that the following packages were not installed or were older than required.

`dbus-glib-1 folks libmuffin gjs-internals-1.0 libgnome-menu-3.0 gconf-2.0 clutter-x11-1.0 libstartup-notification-1.0 gobject-introspection-1.0 libcanberra telepathy-glib telepathy-logger-0.2 polkit-agent-1 libnm-glib libnm-util gnome-keyring-1`

Unfortunately i could not satisfy the versions and dependencies. [Linux Mint](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=1979) claims that "Users can ... switch their sources to follow Testing, or even Unstable, directly to get more frequent updates", so i decided there should not be compatibility problems and just added `deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian main upstream import` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

After that i installed Cinnamon from Linux Mint repositories and when i logged in, there was MATE (i think), not Cinnamon, loaded, with almost unreadable fonts and some other glitches. I decided it is easier to just install LMDE with proper [apt repository priorities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37603/11397), than to install Cinnamon on Debian unstable.

So i ultimately failed at my task, but marked one of the answers as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always download [source code](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/tags) and compile it. For more information read the instruction in the archive and in debian/ directory. Report how it went.

Answer (score 1):

[How about using the source](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?page_id=61), either [the tagged snapshots](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/tags) or [the "bleeding edge" repository](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon).

Seems like what's needed to build a `.deb` package is already around, see [`debian/`](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/tree/master/debian) in the source tree.